# Adding reputation view and inbox view on filtered-by-tag screen:

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, user-experience, ios

I wanted to suggest an improvment to the UX of the mobile app.

**Note:** *I'm running on a mobile (iPhone 5) `iOS` (10.1.1), so I'm tagging this with the `ios` tag. If this is an issue with different operating-systems - please retag.*

When you use the regular **Questions** pane, you see the **rep** and **inbox**, like so: (*the two icons on the upper-right corner*)

[image: question pane screen]

But when you choose to view it through the tag filter, you end up with no rep and inbox on the filtered page, like so:

[image: filtered pane screen]

I wanted to suggest that you add them in the filtered-by-tag view, as some users (like me, on SO...), use filtered questions view **all the time**.

Comment: Is there a way to get answer from someone on the iOS team? Or maybe there is a bugzilla somewhere?

Comment: I don't really want to add inbox/achievements to sub-screens in the app. (Honestly, I hate that they're in the nav bar and we're doing some UI experiments about that.)  If you spend a lot of time in specific tags like Java, you can save the tag sort and then access it from the Questions tab.

Comment: @BrianNickel Thanks for the answer. I feel differently about the inbox/achievements - but you guys probably thought it through. :) Anyways, what do you mean by "save the tag sort"?

Comment: @BrianNickel Nevermind my question - got it! Really helpful! Thanks!